# Photoshop resize all artboards

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting

Is there a way to resize, **not scale,** all artboards or selected artboards on photoshop?
For example, from 1280:720 to 1280:700

Answer (score 3):

Select all artboards - one by one, only Artboards, not content. In Property panel you must see W: 1280 px H:720 px --> turn off the chain between them, and change H: to 700 px